# Firebase: Using callback function to decide whether data is in the database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating search bar, which shows results from database dynamically on keypress, when they match the string that is in the search bar. Also when the string doesn't match anything in my database, I want to show message to user, that nothing matches his input. Problem is that I don't know how to do this in javaScript. I tried using callback function, but my implementation doesn't work. It is my first time using callback function, so I guess something is not right. Can anybody help me? 
Here is simplified code:

```
var bars = firebase.database().ref("bars").orderByChild("rating");
var types = firebase.database().ref("types");
var searcher = document.getElementById("searcher");
var results = document.getElementById("searchResults");
function search(){
    var value = searcher.value.toUpperCase();
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        if(value == null || value == ""){
            results.style.display = "none";
        } else{
            results.innerHTML = "";

            //callback function here
            function findResults(callback) { 
                types.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
                    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                        var type = childSnapshot.key;
                        if(type.toUpperCase().startsWith(value)){
                            results.style.display = "block";
                            var typeItem = createDiv("result-item");
                            typeItem.innerHTML = type;
                            results.append(typeItem);
                        }
                        callback(true);
                    });
                });
                bars.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
                    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                        var bar = childSnapshot.key;
                        if(bar.toUpperCase().startsWith(value)){
                            results.style.display = "block";
                            var barItem = createDiv("result-item");
                            barItem.innerHTML = type;
                            results.append(barItem);
                        }
                        callback(true);
                    });
                });
            }
            //This needs to work, when callback didn't return true
            findResults(function(callback){
                if(!callback){
                    var empty = createDiv("emptyResult");
                    empty.innerHTML = "No matching results";
                    results.appendChild(empty);
                    results.style.display = "block";
                }
            });
        }
    }, 400);    
}

function createDiv(name){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = name;
    return div;
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Let me start by pointing out that querying the Firebase Database on Keypress can be very expensive, since you'll be downloading data more frequently and [Firebase has a price on data downloaded](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing). I recommend querying the database when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> or a Search Button.

2.I don't see why you need a callback function for this. You can use plain functions to achieve that. Like this:

```
function search(){
    var value = searcher.value.toUpperCase();
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        if(value == null || value == ""){
            results.style.display = "none";
        } else{
            results.innerHTML = "";

            types.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
                snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                    var type = childSnapshot.key;
                    var foundUnderTypes = false;
                    if(type.toUpperCase().startsWith(value)){
                        results.style.display = "block";
                        var typeItem = createDiv("result-item");
                        typeItem.innerHTML = type;
                        results.append(typeItem);
                        foundUnderTypes = true;
                    }
                    bars.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
                        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                            var bar = childSnapshot.key;
                            if(bar.toUpperCase().startsWith(value)){
                                results.style.display = "block";
                                var barItem = createDiv("result-item");
                                barItem.innerHTML = type;
                                results.append(barItem);
                            }
                            else{
                                if(!foundUnderTypes)
                                    emptyResult();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }, 400);    
}

function emptyResult(){
    var empty = createDiv("emptyResult");
    empty.innerHTML = "No matching results";
    results.appendChild(empty);
    results.style.display = "block";
}
```